# node js - multi tasking for each item in array

Tags: javascript, node.js, synchronization, multitasking

I am trying to implement a way to upload files asynchronously.
I have a process I want to apply to every item of my array.
I am taking the name of each item, call a API to get additinal information about it, then I am sending it to a text to speech utility, and upload the resulting`wav` file to a S3 instance.

I can't find a way to do this asynchronously, and wait for all of them to finish.

I can do it in serie, but it take lots of time (12 minutes for 30 files (2mb each file)).

I tried to implement a asynchronous way, which takes around 5 minutes (7 minutes less), but I fear the problem is on the net line?

Function to apply to each item:

```
function doAll(c, lan, country, fileName, callback){
    getNews(c, lan)
    .then(function(newsResults){
        getWavFile(newsResults, lan, fileName)
        .then(function(wavResults){
            uploadToS3(country,lan,fileName)
            .then(function(s3Results){
                return callback("done");
            }, function(s3err){
                console.log('s3 error: ',s3err);
                return callback("done");
            })
        }, function(waverr){
            console.log('wav error: ',waverr);
        })
    }, function(newserr){
        console.log('news error: ',newserr);
    })
}
```

Array example :

```
var arr = [
  { 
    _id: '5769369ba2d42fd82ca4d851',
    Name: 'Sports',
    Order: 1,
    Color: 'White',
    Description: 'ספורט',
    UpdatedDate: '2016-07-28T07:44:47.906Z',
    CreatedDate: '2016-06-21T12:44:11.468Z',
    Country: 'IL',
    Langs: [ 
      { 
        Name: 'Sports',
        IsoCode: 'en',
        Url: 'SportsJSON',
        _id: '576b93486c7a9ff025275836' 
      },
      { 
        Name: 'ספורט',
        IsoCode: 'iw',
        Url: 'HebrewSportsJSON',
        _id: '576be6ad56126ccc25852613' 
      } 
    ]
  },
  { 
    _id: '576bf4eb28176a3e5ce15afa',
    Name: 'Top Stories',
    Description: 'הכותרות',
    Color: 'ww',
    Order: 1,
    UpdatedDate: '2016-07-10T12:01:26.713Z',
    CreatedDate: '2016-06-23T14:40:43.435Z',
    Country: 'IL',
    Langs: [
      { 
        Name: 'כותרות',
        Url: 'HebrewTopStoriesJSON',
        IsoCode: 'iw',
        _id: '576bf52228176a3e5ce15afb' 
      },
      { 
        Name: 'Top Stories',
        IsoCode: 'en',
        Url: 'TopStoriesJSON',
        _id: '576bf94d28176a3e5ce15afd' 
      }
    ]
  },
  { 
    _id: '5756d5d6c4a3dfe478b16aa2',
    Description: 'Nation Channel',
    Order: 1,
    Color: 'blue',
    Code: 'Nation',
    Name: 'Nation',
    UpdatedDate: '2016-06-24T22:23:07.198Z',
    CreatedDate: '2016-06-07T14:10:30.699Z',
    Country: 'US',
    Langs: [
      { 
        Name: 'Nation',
        IsoCode: 'en',
        Url: 'NationJson',
        _id: '576db2cb28176a3e5ce15b02' 
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My asynchronous way:

```
var array = [] // see the example how array look like
var newArray= [];
console.log('start uploading files time:', new Date());
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var list = array[i].Langs;
    for (var j= 0; j < list.length; j++) {
        var c = list[j];
        var lan = convertIsoCode(c.IsoCode);
        var fileName = array[i].Name + "_" + lan;
        var country = array[i].Country;
        doAll(c,lan,country,fileName, function(){
            newArray.push(array[i]);
            if (array.length == newArray.length) {
                console.log('done');
                defer.resolve('done');
            }
        })
    }

}
```

**EDIT:**

I tried to do it with `async.each` and `async.parallel`, but didn't succeed, can anyone show me the right way to implement it?

Comment: I don't know much about promises, but it seems `Promise.all` is what you are searching for. [`async.each`](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.each) will also do what you need.

Comment: async.each from what i understand is each function so you can do few function at the same tiime but here its also to do some at the same time an for each item and wait all finish and promise all? not sure cause i need one to wait to the next

Comment: `async.each` support a callback, that will be called once every function ended, or if a error is passed to the callback in any of the functions. Also, you can notify someone when you answer to him by using @DrakaSAN, I only saw your post by luck.

Comment: @DrakaSAN ok i understand i will try using async each for item in array. if you have an example or can show me how to do it in my case will be great

Comment: I am also pretty sure this is a duplicate, but can't find a correct duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removed `newArray` since you don't need it for anything useful, it was wasting CPU time and was a horrendous way of tracking what was done. A simple counter would have done the tricks.

Gone ES6 since it's 2016. Also added semi colon because you were using them inconstitently.

Also, `doAll` is not a meaningful name.

```
'use strict';

const async = require('async');

let array = [/*data*/];

console.log('START ' + (new Date()));
//Asynchronously iterate throught the array
async.each(array, (item, callback) => {
    //item is your array[i]
    async.each(item.Langs, (lang, callback) => {
        //lang is your array[i].Langs[j]
        let lan = convertIsoCode(item.IsoCode),
            fileName = item.Name + '_' + lan,
            country = item.Country;

        //Apply your functions
        getNews(c, lan).then((newsResults) => {
            getWavFile(newsResults, lan, fileName).then((wavResults) => {
                uploadToS3(country,lan,fileName).then((s3Results) => {
                    //Everything is OK, callback without error
                    callback();
                }, (s3err) => {
                    //Raise the error
                    callback(s3err);
                });
            }, (waverr) => {
                console.log('wav error: ',waverr);
                //Raise the error
                callback(waverr);
            });
        }, (newserr) => {
            console.log('news error: ',newserr);
            //Raise the error
            callback(newserr);
        });
    }, (error) => {
        callback(error);
    });
}, (error) => {
    //If a error was raised, everything pending will be aborted and the error will be displayed
    if(error) {
        console.log(error);
    //Else, just report it did fine
    } else {
        console.log('OK');
    }
});
```

Comment: I would advice you to either rewrite the code is ES5, or the rest of your code in ES6, and using tools like `eslint` to ensure you have a consistent style, it will help you improve yourself and not get lost when you revisit your code months laters.

Comment: i will Thank you very much